# Longest decrease subsequence subarray in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I encountered this question:

**Find longest decrease sequence in an array**

So basically, if [3,1,**4,3,2,1**,2,3] is given, it will return [4,3,2,1] as the longest sequence within it. I was able to solve this question with O(n^2) time complexity but I feel like I can do O(n).

I know I am probably making a giant logic mistake but this is how I approach with 2 pointers method.

```
function findDecreaseSubArray(arr) {
  let subList = [arr[0]];
  // let maxLength= 0;
  let left = 0;

  for (let right = 1; right < arr.length; right++) {
    // maxLength = (maxLength, windowEnd - windowStart + 1);

    if (arr[left] > arr[right]) {
      subList.push(arr[right]);
    }else{
      subList.shift();
      left = right-1;
    }
  }
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is moving left and right pointers if left element is larger than right, and if so, push both elements into **sublist** array.

My brain starts giving **404** error after this, so there are 2 subarrays that are decreasing, one of them is [3,1] and the other one is [4,3,2,1].

How could I track one subarray is larger than the other subarray? Or there is a better way to approach this solution?

Any hints, hands, code snippet would highly appreciated. (And sorry about my code snippet, I know it is shitty but I just wanted to display some of my thoughts on code)

Answer (score 3):

You just have to iterate over the array once, but keep track of the start and length of the longest sequence as you progress through it:

```js
var arr = [3,1,4,3,2,1,2,3];

function findDecreaseSubArray(arr) {
  let startIndex = 0;
  let length = 1;

  let longestSequence = {
    startIndex: 0,
    length: 1
  }

  arr.forEach((element, index, arr) => {
    if (index === 0) return;

    if (element < arr[index -1]) {
      length += 1;
    } else {      
      length = 1;
      startIndex = index;
    }

    if (length > longestSequence.length) {
        longestSequence.length = length;
        longestSequence.startIndex = startIndex;
    }

  })

  return longestSequence;
}

console.log(findDecreaseSubArray(arr));
```

Answer (score 2):

This approach supports [VLAZ's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59625588/longest-decrease-subsequence-subarray-in-javascript/59625734#comment105413828_59625734) and uses only the indices of the array.

```js
function longestDecreasing(array) {
    var longest,
        start = 0,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (!i || array[i] < array[i - 1]) continue;
        if (!longest || longest[1] - longest[0] < i - start) longest = [start, i];
        start = i;
    }

    return array.slice(...longest && longest[1] - longest[0] > i - start
        ? longest
        : [start, i]);
}

console.log(longestDecreasing([3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3]))
```

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easier to iterate normally, from the first index to the end, while pushing sequential sequences to an array, which gets reset when a number greater than the last is found. When resetting, assign the resulting sequence array to a more permanent variable *if* it's longer than the array in that permanent variable:

```js
const findDecreaseSubArray = (arr) => {
  let longestSoFar = [];
  let currentSequence = [];
  const reset = (newItem) => {
    if (currentSequence.length > longestSoFar.length) {
      longestSoFar = currentSequence;
    }
    currentSequence = [newItem];
  };
  for (const item of arr) {
    if (currentSequence.length && item > currentSequence[currentSequence.length - 1]) {
      reset(item);
    } else {
      currentSequence.push(item);
    }
  }
  reset();
  return longestSoFar;
};
console.log(findDecreaseSubArray([3,1,4,3,2,1,2,3]));
```

Comment: "*It would probably be easier to iterate normally, from the first index to the end, while pushing sequential sequences to an array*" I was thinking this as well. The only (very slight) drawback is the extra space for the array. It shouldn't really be a problem, to be honest, but if space complexity is to be reduced, you can just keep indexes for `start` and `stop` that denote the longest sequence in the array. Thus the length is `stop - start` and you can extract the section from `arr[start]` to `arr[stop]` at the end. The space complexity becomes `O(1)` but it complicates the implementation.

Comment: @TKoL yep, it seems so.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code.

```js
function getLongestDecreaseSequence(arr) {
  if (
    Object.prototype.toString.call(arr) !== "[object Array]" ||
    arr.length == 0
  ) {
    return arr;
  }

  let longestArr = [];
  let tmpArr = [],
    lastTmpIndex = -1;

  arr.forEach((value, i) => {
    if (arr[lastTmpIndex] < value) {
      tmpArr = [];
    }
    // no matter what, I will put it in tmpArray
    lastTmpIndex = i;
    tmpArr.push(value);

    if (longestArr.length < tmpArr.length) {
      longestArr = tmpArr;
    }
  });
  return longestArr;
}

console.log(getLongestDecreaseSequence([3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a reducing job.

```js
var a =  [3,1,4,3,2,1,2,3],
    r = a.reduce( function(r,e){
                    var l = r[r.length-1];
                    return l[l.length-1] > e ? ( l.push(e)
                                               , r
                                               )
                                             : ( r.push([e])
                                               , r
                                               );
                  }
                , [[]]
                )
         .reduce((p,c) => p.length > c.length ? p : c);
console.log(r);
```